# Можно ли сократить данный код?

Tags: python

Переменная присваивает строку, которая после пойдет в таблицу (csv). Мне нужно, чтобы при отсутствии строки возвращалась пустая строка "", чтобы таблица не ломалась. Можно ли сократить этот код? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите функцию-обёртку, в которой делается try: driver.find... except: return “” и вызывайте эту функцию везде

Comment: Добавьте код текстом вместо картинки. Для этого нажмите под вопросом "править", вставьте код, выделите, нажмите кнопку `{}` над редактором текста.

Comment: Я бы предложил наоборот увеличить количество строк :) А именно - вынести пути в отдельный словарь типа `paths = {'title_path': ..., 'city_path': ...}` и так далее. А в функцию передавать уже элемент словаря `find_element_by_xpath(paths['title_path'])`

Comment: Не стоит использовать картинки вместо кода. Вы лишаете отвечающих возможности просто поправить ваш код в нужную сторону, а набирать никто не будет. Следовательно, вангую, на данном вопросе вы лишились двух-четырёх человек, которые могли бы помочь, но их остановила картинка.

Answer (score 2):

Можно устроить извращенства с циклом, `try` `except` и словарем. Но не уверен, что это стоит делать:)

Answer (score 2):

```py
# Определить функцию, которая будет получать элемент по path 
# или давать пустую строку
def get_element_or_blank(driver, path):
    try:
        result = driver.get_element_by_xpath(path).text
    except:
        result = ''
    return result

# Вынести пути в отдельный словарь
pathes = {
    'title': "html/body...etc", 
    'city': "html/body...etc2"
}

# Получаем нужные значения с помощью функции
if private.find('Private') != -1:
    title = get_element_or_blank(driver, pathes['title'])
    city= get_element_or_blank(driver, pathes['city'])
```

Comment: А в питоне нельзя циклом пройтись по элементам словаря?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME не уверен, что это так уж сильно здесь нужно